# Image and text change on checkbox checked and revert back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have looked everywhere but doesn't find the answer or can't understand it.
I want my image and text change on checkbox checked and when the checkbox is unchecked it'll revert back.When i click the checkbox the image and text changes but doesn't revert back to original.

```js
$("#link_checkbox").click(function() {
  $(".result_text").text("Inserts the contents of the file into your document and creates a shortcut to the source file.Changes to the source file will be reflected in your document.");
  $('#picture').attr('src', 'image/result1.png');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first_checkbox">
  <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="link_checkbox" id="link_checkbox" class="link_checkbox" value="link_checkbox" accesskey="k" />
     </span>
  <span class="first_checkbox_lbl">
     <label for="link_checkbox">Lin<u>k</u> to file</label>
     </span>
</div>
<span class="result_img">
      <img id="picture" src="image/result.png" alt="result.png" />
    </span>
<div class="result_text">Inserts the contents of the file into your document so that you can edit it later using the application which created the source file.</div>
```

Comment: You want to do if checkbox is checked then change image and text and if checkbox is unchecked then revert back to original right?

Comment: yes exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put condition like that if `checkbox` is checked then replace image/text with you want and if `unchecked` replace it with original.

```
$("#link_checkbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".result_text").text("Inserts the contents of the file into your document and creates a shortcut to the source file.Changes to the source file will be reflected in your document.");
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'image/result1.png');
    } else {
        $(".result_text").text("Original text you want to add");
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'image/original-file.png');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this jQuery code.

```
$("#link_checkbox").click(function(){

            if($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                $(".result_text").text("checked."); // Any text this just for testing.
                $('#picture').attr('src', '{image path}'); 
            }
            else
            {
                $(".result_text").text("unchecked.");// Any text this just for testing.
                $('#picture').attr('src', '{image path}'); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make another div with the new data you want to show with display: none; and whenever you click on something to change the fields, just hide the first div and show the other one (can be achieved with $('selector).toggle(); )

```
<div class="div1">
    <p>my text</p><img src="img.jpg>
</div>

<div class="div2" style="display:none;">
    <p>my other text</p><img src="other_img.jpg>
</div>
$('selector').on('click', function(){
  $('.div1, .div2).toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#link_checkbox").click(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("link_checkbox").checked == true)
    {
        $(".result_text").text("Inserts the contents of the file into your document and creates a shortcut to the source file.Changes to the source file will be reflected in your document.");
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'image/result1.png'); 
    }
    else
    {
         $(".result_text").text("Inserts the contents of the file into your document so that you can edit it later using the application which created the source file.");
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'image/result.png'); 
    }
});
```

Try this code